# AngularJS Directives in ng-repeat

Tags: jquery, angularjs, sparklines

I'm trying to use Angular's ng-repeat to display jQuery sparklines.  I've wrapped the sparkline in what the angular directive to tell it to call. It seems that despite having a postlink in there it still is call the sparklines too early.  I've attached my code below:

```
var Timeline = angular.module('Timeline', []);
  Timeline.directive('sparkline', function () {
    return {
    restrict: 'E', 
    scope: { 
      val: '=',
    },
        link: function postLink(scope, iElement, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('scalars', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    $(iElement).sparkline('html', { 
           type:'bar', barColor:'#1e42c8', height:'40px', barWidth:10 , barSpacing:2
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="row" ngChange:false ng-repeat="(description,scalars) in vitals | orderBy:orderProp">
  <div class="span4">
    <p><sparkline exp="data" class="sparkline">{{scalars.join(',')}}</sparkline></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems more like it might be an issue with how the jquery plugin "sparkline" sets itself up. Since the elements are being added dynamically by Angular, perhaps there's something getting gummed up when you're trying to apply the plugin. Do you have a fiddle that demonstrates what's wrong?

Answer (score 5):

For anyone bouncing into this question: For a working sparklines directive, I suggest you check this fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/m48u/h8PdR/15/ (**not by me**). The directive itself looks like so -

```
myapp.directive("bulletcharksparkline", function() {
return {
    restrict:"E",
    scope:{
        data:"@"
    },
    //template: "<div class='tpl'></div>",
    compile: function(tElement,tAttrs,transclude){
        tElement.replaceWith("<span>"+tAttrs.data+"</span>");
        return function(scope, element, attrs){
            attrs.$observe("data", function(newValue){
                element.html(newValue);
                element.sparkline('html',{type:'bullet'});
            });
        };
    }
};
});
```

Comment: Try this fixed one: http://jsfiddle.net/NAA5G/ This was just due to Github returning a plain text MIME type for the Angular-UI JS. Either Chrome or Github changed behavior from the time the fiddle worked.